# Running balance amount from Paypal API

Tags: api, paypal

I would like to get the running balance of my PayPal account after each and every transaction.
I'm getting the same from the portal in a nice report format under "balance" column.

But I get no running balance when I'm using "TransactionSearch" and "GetTransactionDetails".
There is an API name "GetBalance", but it gives me the total balance which is what I don't required.

It would be really appreciated if you please help me getting this running balance after each and every transaction using the above two APIs.

Thanks much,
Arnab

Answer (score 0):

The closest API to what you are looking for would be the GetBalance API.  This should be the same balance that you see available in your PayPal account.